# How do I return true if nested array is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning Rails and am a bit stuck.

I am using the simple-navigation gem and building a custom renderer and I want to add a bootstrap icon to an HTML element if the configuration option is present. I am getting an error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" and I think it has to do with my method. I have tried to define the method as:

```
content_tag('span', (content_tag(:i, nil, :class => item.html_options[:opts][:icon]) + item.name if have_icon?), link_options_for(item).except(:method))

def have_icon?(item)
    !item.html_options[:opts][:icon].blank?
end
```

I am not sure I wrote the content_tag correctly. In fact I am sure I didn't. I also think I am getting the "Wrong number of arguments" because `item.html_options[:opts]` or `item.html_options[:opts][:icon]` is missing, therefor pointing out my method is poorly written.

Can someone help?

---

EDIT:

I rewrote the code and it works but my question still stands so I might get better at coding. So my question is, is the `have_icon?` method correct or how would I rewrite it to return a boolean if both the `[:opts]` and `[:opts][:icon]` are present?

This is working code:

```
content_tag('span', name_with_icon(item), link_options_for(item).except(:method))

def name_with_icon(item)
  if item.html_options[:opts]
    if item.html_options[:opts][:icon]
      content_tag(:i, nil, :class => item.html_options[:opts][:icon]) + item.name
    else
      item.name
    end
  else
    item.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Your method takes a parameter. Your call doesn't provide one.

Comment: Well that was obvious... Thanks!!! I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly (I can never remember if it's `get` or `fetch` to access hash values):

```
def name_with_icon(item)
  icon = item.html_options[:opts].andand.fetch[:icon]
  content = icon ? content_tag(:i, nil, class: icon) : ""
  "#{content}#{item.name}"
end
```

This assumes the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/), or you can use `try`.